# Error when trying to install snap application

Tags: software-installation, snap

I get this error when I try to install a snap application:

```
$ sudo snap install notes
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "core" (1689) from channel "stable" 
(Get https://068ed04f23.site.internapcdn.net/download-snap/99T7MUlRhtI3U0QFgl5mXXESAiSwt776_1689.snap?t=2017-05-18T16:17:18Z&h=6a735f4388adcdba94c2d95a93fa5f36cde25a87: net/http: TLS handshake timeout)
```

Comment: If you try again, do you get the same issue? What kind of connection to the internet are you on?

Comment: i get this issues when i try to install anbox

Comment: How are you trying to do that? Please [edit] your question to add commands or procedure you used and the output

Comment: I think it's your connection where the problem is. Check your internet connect

Comment: What's the output of `wget -nv -SO /dev/null 'https://068ed04f23.site.internapcdn.net/download-snap/99T7MUlRhtI3U0QFgl5mXXESAiSwt776_1689.snap?t=2017-05-18T16:17:18Z&h=6a735f4388adcdba94c2d95a93fa5f36cde25a87'`?